# gunicorn <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' due to lack of virtual machine resource?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, gunicorn

I have read the posts with similar tittles and nothing seem to solve my issue. We are running a django app with gunicorn, supervisor and nginx for a few months now without any problems. This morning, out of the nowhere (I repeat out of nowhere!), I get a `502 bad gateway error` when trying to access any page of the site.

after looking into it, I found that gunicorn was at fault, as shown in this gunicorn.err.log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in run
    self.sleep()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 357, in sleep
    ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
    self.reap_workers()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 228, in run
    super().run()
 File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
    self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
    self.stop()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
    time.sleep(0.1)
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
    self.reap_workers()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

I am capable of understanding what is the source of the error according to this log. Any help would be hugely appreciated before I get fired!

after trying to run gunicorn with `--debug-log debug` command, I get additional traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 162, in init_process
    super().init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'inventory4'
```

Inventory4 is my django directory with the settings.py and wsgi.py

this is super strange because I have not made any modification to my project configuration.

here is what it looks like in django:
settings.py:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'inventory4.wsgi.application'
```

and wsgi.py

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'inventory4.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and then in /etc/supervisor/conf.d/gunicorn.conf:

```
directory=/home/ubuntu/exostocksaas
command=/home/ubuntu/exo/bin/gunicorn  --config /home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/config.py --log-level debug --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/exostocksaas/app.sock inventory4.wsgi:application

autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.out.log


[group:guni]
programs:gunicorn
```

I have no clue what could have caused the bug to occur and how to solve it